# HTML grid layout with border-collapse

Tags: html, css

I have a list of data on a Web page that I want to display as a grid. Classically, I might have done this using `<table>`, but the data is not semantically tabular, and so there's no reason to have a fixed number of columns (I would like the cells to wrap around automatically, and reflow as the width of the parent element changes).

I can do this by setting the display elements to `display: inline-block` and setting their `width`. This does what I want in terms of layout. However, it also causes problems when I want to set a `border`; the border is shown doubled between elements, and only single on the outside.

If I were using a table, I would set `border-collapse: collapse`, which would make it work. But this doesn't seem to do anything with the `inline-block` solution.

How can I collapse the borders between consecutive `inline-block` elements? Or is there some other way of making a grid layout to allow this?

Comment: This may help: [Fighting the space between inline block elements](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nowdays you might use flex .

For the borders, you may draw them from a shadow and add a negative margin to overlap them:

```css
ul , li{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  padding:1em;
}
li {
  min-width:40px;/* you can let content decide */
  min-height:40px;/* you can let content decide */
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px;
  margin:0 -1px -1px 0;
  /* flex makes also x,y alignement easy */
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>21</li>
  <li>22</li>
  <li>23</li>
  <li>24</li>
  <li>25</li>
  <li>26</li>
  <li>27</li>
  <li>28</li>
  <li>29</li>
  <li>30</li>
  <li>31</li>
  <li>32</li>
  <li>33</li>
  <li>34</li>
  <li>35</li>
  <li>36</li>
  <li>37</li>
  <li>38</li>
  <li>39</li>
  <li>40</li>
  <li>41</li>
  <li>42</li>
  <li>43</li>
  <li>44</li>
  <li>45</li>
  <li>46</li>
  <li>47</li>
  <li>48</li>
  <li>49</li>
  <li>50</li>
  <li>51</li>
  <li>52</li>
  <li>53</li>
  <li>54</li>
  <li>55</li>
  <li>56</li>
  <li>57</li>
  <li>58</li>
  <li>59</li>
  <li>60</li>
  <li>61</li>
  <li>62</li>
  <li>63</li>
  <li>64</li>
  <li>65</li>
  <li>66</li>
  <li>67</li>
  <li>68</li>
  <li>69</li>
  <li>70</li>
  <li>71</li>
  <li>72</li>
  <li>73</li>
  <li>74</li>
  <li>75</li>
  <li>76</li>
  <li>77</li>
  <li>78</li>
  <li>79</li>
  <li>80</li>
  <li>81</li>
  <li>82</li>
  <li>83</li>
  <li>84</li>
  <li>85</li>
  <li>86</li>
  <li>87</li>
  <li>88</li>
  <li>89</li>
  <li>90</li>
  <li>91</li>
  <li>92</li>
  <li>93</li>
  <li>94</li>
  <li>95</li>
  <li>96</li>
  <li>97</li>
  <li>98</li>
  <li>99</li>
  <li>100</li>
</ul>
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/BpMpZb

Comment: Turns out setting `margin: -1px` works with the `inline-block` method as well.

Comment: @TomHunt yes it does with any adequat display or float . the thing about flex is that: it makes everybox of a row the same height where float or inline-block/inline-table fails unless you fix an height that can be overflowed by content :)

Answer (score 1):

Some possible solutions floating through my head:

1) Set margins of blocks negative according to where they are. You could have classes (i.e. right-edge, left-edge, sandwiched) and manipulate the margins so the borders overlap.

2) Set the left and right borders to 0px for blocks in the middle. Two ways I'd go by:

```
CSS
.sandwiched {border:1px 0px 1px 0px;}
.sandwiched {border-left:0px; border-right:0px;}
```

EDIT: It's a good idea to learn about the whitespace annoyance linked to in the comment. Just be aware that applying that fix will shift the pixels you need to adjust.